# Find and Highlight Macro with Confirmation

Tags: vba, excel, highlight

I have this macro below that works great for finding a number and confirming if it is correct (then highlighting). First it asks what number your looking for then you enter the number and hit OK. Then if it finds the number then you will have a chance to say yes no or cancel (just in case their are multiple numbers you are looking for and its not the right one). If you hit yes it will highlight the cell.

The problem:

1. If the number you are looking for isn't on the sheet, the macro will error.
2. If you hit "NO" I would like it to look for the next number and if their is no next number then just exit. (This button could also be called "Next" as it would be more accurately describe the situation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
Sub find_highlight()
    Dim w As Variant
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim ans As String

    Do
        w = InputBox("What to find?")

        Cells.Find(What:=(w), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False).Activate

        Select Case MsgBox("Is this the number?", vbYesNoCancel)

            Case vbNo

            Case vbYes
                With Selection.Interior
                    .ColorIndex = 6
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                End With

            Case vbCancel
                Exit Do

        End Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: MSDN is a great resource!   Look at this as it answers your questions, shows you how to check if nothing is found in the find and how to find.Next : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel

Comment: "Note: Your Activate statement will fail if the Find does not match anything (because Nothing.Activate is invalid), but that is a question for another day." I guess today is another day! LOL  (Sorry, don't have time to help you out again this morning - will have to leave it for someone else.)

Answer (score 1):

you really should split this into multiple posts.  One problem per post, please.

As for the error you're seeing: you have to check for an error condition.

```
Sub find_highlight()
    Dim w As Variant
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim ans As String

    Do
        w = InputBox("What to find?")

        On Error Resume Next
        thisRng1 = ActiveCell.Address
        Cells.Find(What:=(w), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False).Activate
        thisRng2 = ActiveCell.Address
        If thisRng1 = thisRng2 Then
            MsgBox "Value Not Found"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        Select Case MsgBox("Is this the number?", vbYesNoCancel)

            Case vbNo

            Case vbYes
                With Selection.Interior
                    .ColorIndex = 6
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                End With

            Case vbCancel
            Exit Do

        End Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Good call, I didn't test the code much since it started into a whole other host of strange behavior.  Changed to `thisRng1 = ActiveCell.Address`, that should cover it.  I see where you're going with using better programming principles, maybe I'll dig into this later.

Answer (score 1):

The following code:

- allows the user to exit the procedure by simply not giving a value to search for
- looks in "values" instead of in "formulas" (simply because I suspect that you are wanting to search in the results of formulas, not the formulas themselves - i.e. if you had a formula of `=5+4` you would want to match it if the user was searching for `9`, not if they were searching for `4`)
- avoids the error, which occurs when you try to `Activate` the cell where the match occurs when no match has occurred, by not trying to `Activate` it until a test has been performed to ensure a match occurred
- exits the search for a value if the user has said "No" so often that it has returned to the first match

```
Sub find_highlight()
    Dim w As Variant
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim FirstMatch As String
    Dim ans As String

    Do
        w = InputBox("What to find?")
        If w = "" Then
            'Exit the procedure if the user gave us nothing to look for
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Don't activate the cell straight away
        'Search in values instead of in formulas
        Set FoundCell = Cells.Find(What:=w, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False)

        'Check to see if we found a match
        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            'Store where the first match was found
            FirstMatch = FoundCell.Address
            Do
                Application.GoTo FoundCell  'safer than FoundCell.Activate
                Select Case MsgBox("Is this the number?", vbYesNoCancel)

                    Case vbNo

                    Case vbYes
                        With FoundCell.Interior
                            .ColorIndex = 6
                            .Pattern = xlSolid
                            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        End With
                        'Found and processed, quit looking for this particular value
                        Exit Do

                    Case vbCancel
                        'Quit the entire procedure - user doesn't want to search any more
                        Exit Sub

                End Select

                'Find the next match
                Set FoundCell = Cells.FindNext()
                'If back at the first match, quit this loop
                If FoundCell.Address = FirstMatch Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```